# Initialize Variable Inside Compound Literal

Tags: c, struct, compound-literals

I'm fairly new to C and only just stumbled onto Compound Literals so please correct me if my question is inaccurate.

I have a struct;

```
typedef struct
{
  int someVal;
} foo;
```

Now I understand this could be initialized with the following.

```
int main()
{
  foo thisFoo = (foo) { .someVal = 2 };
}
```

My question is, could I initialize `someVal` with a void function?

```
void init(int *f);

int main()
{
  foo thisFoo = (foo) { init(.someVal) }; // error: expected expression before '.' token
}

void init(int *f)
{
  *f = 2;
}
```

I've managed to initialize the struct itself and its respective members in a function without any problems but was curious if this is an alternative (or even reasonable) choice?

Comment: `foo thisFoo; init(&thisFoo.someVal);`... `void init(int *f)
{
  *f  = 2;
}`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't think he wants the function to know about the structure.

Comment: @Barmar sure, I modified coment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't initialize like that. You could create the structure without initialization, and then call the function with the address of the member.

```
foo thisFoo;
init(&thisFoo.someVal);
```

Comment: I appreciate it, I figured it might've been a silly question :)